# Problemas na Sintaxe Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, vue.js

Galera , hoje instalei o Vue.js para iniciar meu primeiro projeto e me deparei com o seguinte problema.
Após a instalação criei o projeto e quando abri o arquivo app.vue o vs code estava lendo como se fosse um texto normal , estava todos os códigos em branco.
Alguém sabe oque devo fazer para resolver ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que o sintax highlight não está ativo, em outros IDEs como o Atom ou Webstorm isso instala-se como plugin. Será esse o caso?

Comment: Exatamente isso mano Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de uma extensão pra isso.

A própria comunidade recomenda o [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur)

Comment: Perfeito amigo obrigado!